# Creating a bootable DMG or ISO for Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, osx-mountain-lion

I have a 4.04GB DMG file for Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), which is being used for reinstalling the OS on my MacBook Pro.

However, the bootable USB needs a GPT (GUID-partition table) format. The only compatible format is FAT32, which supports a maximum of 4.00 GB per partition.

Is there any way to compress the DMG file to be smaller than 4GB, or booting from an ISO file?

I'm using Windows 7 on an HP Pavilion laptop. The .img file is 4.04 GB, and I need to copy that file to a USB stick that supports it. What format should I use in my 32 GB SanDisk USB stick while on the Windows 7 computer in order to read/write?

Comment: I'm creating the bootable USB on Windows 7. I have the .dmg file here.

Comment: Nope. The thing here is that the DMG file is 4.04 GB, and it needs to be smaller than 4.00 GB to be supported in a FAT32 USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

simply format your boot USB Stick with exFAT which can handle >4GB files fine and will be recognized by UEFI (and BIOS). just tested with and quite old MacBook Air

Comment: macOS (or OS X, for that matter) support of exFAT is sketchy, at best, so that could be a problem down the road. If the drive has been formatted in Windows, it could work, or not, depending on the block size you use during formatting, and that's hit-or-miss: default cluster size in exFAT for a 32GB drive should be 32KB IF the drive is registered as being 32GB in capacity, not IF the available capacity is 32GB after reformatting/partitioning. If the drive's original capacity is over 32GB (and you plan on using only 32GB in a single partition), then default cluster size is 128KB. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 bottom line is, Format your drive in a Mac if you plan to use it on a Mac and/or Windows.